# Why I can't use text editor to edit randomize_va_space

Tags: shell, vim, sh

I have did search and people say that I must use
`sudo sh -c ’echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to edit this file. Can someone explain to me why? 
When I use vim with root to edit this file and save it shows an error: `"/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space" E667: Fsync failed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in /proc are not regular files. They are in fact kernel variables exposed through filesystem for easier access. Because of that, they don't support all functions of "normal" files, namely, `fsync`.

The text editor doesn't know that it's dealing with a special file and tries to use some unsupported function. On the other hand, `echo ... > file` works because it does not use `fsync` function.

`fsync` is a function that tells the OS to write any pending changes from file to disk.